# If the red curve is an ellipse, is the green curve also an ellipse?

Tags: geometry

See the figure below:

[image]

The red curve is an ellipse; the blue curve is a unit circle.

Green curve is the locus of the circle center.

Is the green curve an ellipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the produced curve is not an ellipse; consider a high-eccentricity ellipse.